# How can I pass a string type value into a Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, dynamic

I am trying to call this procedure with the following parameters:

```
proc2_del_rows('EMP', 'JOB = CLERK')
```

But this results in an error. Why?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc2_del_rows
        (v_tname        VARCHAR2,
         v_condition    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL)
AS
        sql_stmt        VARCHAR2(500);
        where_clause    VARCHAR2(200) := 'WHERE'||' '||v_condition;
BEGIN
        IF v_condition IS NULL THEN
            where_clause := NULL;
        END IF;

        sql_stmt := 'DELETE FROM :1'||' '||where_clause;

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt USING v_tname;
        COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: What is the error? And which DBMS?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling it with the condition set to 'JOB = CLERK'. This won't work, as CLERK needs to have quotes around it. To embed quotes in a quote-delimited string, double them up: 'JOB = ''CLERK'''

```
proc2_del_rows('EMP', 'JOB = ''CLERK''')
```

The error in the first comment below is due to incorrect syntax for the table in the query. Try:

```
sql_stmt := 'DELETE FROM '|| v_tname ||' '||where_clause;

 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
```

Comment: BEGIN proc2_del_rows ('EMP', 'JOB="CLERK" ');
Error at line 1
ORA-00903: invalid table name
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.PROC2_DEL_ROWS", line 14
ORA-06512: at line 1

Script Terminated on line 1.